# Showing that a function from the unit sphere to $SO(2)$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

Consider the usual unit sphere $S^1$ and the group $SO(2).$ There are several equivalent definitions for this two, the ones I am using follows below.

$$ S^1 = \{ x = (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2\colon x_1 = \cos \theta \, \wedge x_2 = \sin \theta, \, \theta \in [0,2\pi]\}.$$

$$ SO(2)  = \Bigg\{ A \in Mat(2,\mathbb R)\colon A = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}, \, \theta \in [0,2\pi] \Bigg\}.$$

Now, consider the map $f\colon S^1 \to SO(2)$ defined by
$$ f(\cos\theta , \sin \theta) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}.$$
I am trying to prove that $f$ is a homemorphism between $S^1$ and $SO(2)$ (consequently, both spaces must be homeomorphic). I was able to prove bijectivity and was also able to find the inverse of $f$, $g\colon SO(2) \to S^1$ which is defined by
$$ g\Bigg( \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}\Bigg) = (\cos \theta,\sin \theta).$$
I am having trouble with proving the continuity of $f$ and $g$, thought. I believe this can be done reffering to "coordinate functions" somehow, but I am not really familiar with those.

Any help is apreciatted.

Comment: I would use the isomorphism $\cos \theta + \sin \theta i  \rightarrow  \cos \theta I + \sin \theta J$ with $I$ the identity matrix and $J$ the appropriate counterpart. Now it's just multiplication on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField  What do you mean by "appropriate counterpart" ?

Comment: I mean $J$ is forced to be an antisymmetric matrix with a $1$ in the top right. You can see the decomposition by considering matrices containing the sine and cosine portions separately. If you're not familiar with this isomorphism you can prove $a + bi \rightarrow aI +bJ$ for all of $\mathbb{C}$ by considering all matrices of the form $aI +bJ$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. You may also want to investigate the characteristic equation for $J$ to motivate this isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that $S^1$ and $\operatorname{SO}(2)$ are both compact and Hausdorff. This means, that just from $f$ and $g$ being bijective and continuous, you can already conclude, that they are homeomorphisms (which also means you only need one of the maps to prove both spaces are homeomorphic) using the following two theorems:

1. Continuous maps from compact spaces to Hausdorff spaces are closed (and proper). See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/maps%20from%20compact%20spaces%20to%20Hausdorff%20spaces%20are%20closed%20and%20proper).
2. A bijective continuous map, which is open/closed (they imply each other, see [here](https://9to5science.com/a-bijective-continuous-map-is-a-homeomorphism-iff-it-is-open-or-equivalently-iff-it-is-closed)), is a homeomorphism.

Note, that both $S^1$ and $\operatorname{SO}(2)$ are metric spaces, so you can also use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterium to prove continuity (with which you can reduce it on the continuity of $\sin$ and $\cos$), instead of proving, that preimages of open sets are open.

Comment: So, one can use the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity to show that both $f,g$ are continuous?

Comment: Yes. On $S^1$ you can simply take the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{C}$, but I think it would probably be simpler to take the one constructed with the bijection $[0,2\pi[\rightarrow S^1,t\mapsto e^{it}$: We have $d(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2})=|\theta_1-\theta_2|$, if this value is $\leq\pi$ and $d(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2})=2\pi-|\theta_1-\theta_2|$, if this value is $\geq\pi$. Of course, if you consider small neighborhoods, you will only need to look at the first case, which is a very simple formula.

Comment: For the metric on $\operatorname{SO}(2)$, I would take either the one induced by the $1$-norm ($\|A\|_1=\max_j\sum_i|a_{ij}|$, which is $|\sin\theta|+|\cos\theta|$ for a $\operatorname{SO}(2)$ matrix (with the maximum over the two columns being irrelevant)) or the $\infty$-norm ($\|A\|_\infty=\max_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|$, which is $|\sin\theta|+|\cos\theta|$ as well): We have $d(f(e^{i\theta_1}),f(e^{i\theta_2}))=\|f(e^{i\theta_1})-f(e^{i\theta_2})\|=|\sin\theta_1-\sin\theta_2|+|\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_2|$, where you see immediatly, that it just falls back to $\sin$ and $\cos$ being continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Choose homeomorphisms $\varphi:(0,\pi)\cup(\pi,2\pi)\rightarrow U$ defined by $\varphi(\theta)= (\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$, where the coordinate neighborhood $U=S^1-\{(\pm1,0)\}$, and $\phi:(0,\pi)\cup(\pi,2\pi)\rightarrow V$ defined by $\phi(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}$, where the neoghtborhood $V=\text{SO}(2)-\{\begin{pmatrix} \pm1 & 0 \\ 0 & \pm1 \end{pmatrix}\}$. Then $\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ \varphi(\theta)=\theta$ and $\varphi^{-1}\circ g\circ \phi(\theta)=\theta$ are continuous and thus $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $U$ and $V$, reapectively. Similrly, choose homeomorphisms $\varphi:(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\cup(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})\rightarrow U'$ defined by $\varphi(\theta)= (\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$, where the coordinate neighborhood $U'=S^1-\{(0,\pm1)\}$, and $\phi:(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\cup(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})\rightarrow V'$ defined by $\phi(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}$, where the neoghtborhood $V'=\text{SO}(2)-\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \pm1 \\ \mp1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\}$. Then $\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ \varphi(\theta)=\theta$ and $\varphi^{-1}\circ g\circ \phi(\theta)=\theta$ are continuous and thus $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $U'$ and $V'$, respectively. Since $U\cup U'=S^1$ and $V\cup V'=\text{SO}(2)$, these $f$ and $g$ are countinuous.